# В какой среде чаще всего программируют на С++?

Tags: windows, ide, c++

В какой среде чаще всего программируют на С++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio / Visual C++! )))

К сожалению, на Ваш вопрос нет однозначного ответа. Хотя бы потому, что под Linux используют одни IDE а под Windows - другие.

Поскольку под Linux'ом я программировал мало, предлагаю (самую) популярную среду под Windows...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, я и имел в виду под Windows.)) 
Почему спрашиваю. Просто собираюсь выучить какую-нибудь среду для работы с С++, но вот встретил их очень много. К примеру мне приглянулась Borland C++ Builder. Очень напоминает среду для VisualBasic. Однако хотелось бы писать в том, где чаще работают программисты в фирмах.

Answer (score 1):

visual studio 2010,

devC++.

Answer (score 0):

Code::Blocks

Answer (score 0):

На Microsoft Vicual Studio

Можно встретить программистов на RAD Studio